# How Do Insert a char in string (java/groovy)?

Tags: java, groovy

I have a string like :

```
string = abcdefghabcd
```

Now lets say I want to replace the first occurrence of `a`. I tried something like this :

```
string[string.indexOf('a')] = '0'
```

But this doesn't seems to be working. Any other way I can do  this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java you can use [String.replaceFirst()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) :

```
String s = "abcdefghabcd";
s = s.replaceFirst("a", "0");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output will be :

```
0bcdefghabcd
```

Warning : the `replaceFirst()` method takes a regex : so if you want to replace a special character like `[` you need to escape by putting a `\` before it. `\` being a special character itself, you need to double it as follow :

```
s = s.replaceFirst("\\[", "0");
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) is the documentation on Java Regular Expressions. Also, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/manipstrings.html) is Oracle's Java tutorial on manipulating Characters in Strings.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I want to replace `"["` with `0`. I get `Caught: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0` error.

Comment: batman: that's because replaceFirst expects a regular expression, and "[" is a special character in regex.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware that strings in Java are immutable.  They cannot be changed.  Any method you use to "change" a string will have to return a new string.  If you want to modify a string directly you will need to use a mutable string type like StringBuilder.

There are many methods in the [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) API docs that will help you get a modified version of your string, including s.replace(), s.replaceAll(),s.replaceFirst(), ... or you could use a combination of substring and "+" to create a new string.

If you really want to treat the string as an array as in your initial example, you could use String.getChars to get an array of characters, manipulate that, and then use the String constructor String(char[]) to convert back to a String object.

Answer (score 1):

In this program you will need use replaceFirst() method of String class in Java.

```
  /*
Java String replace example.
This Java String Replace example describes how replace method of java String
class can be used to replace character or substring by new one.
*/

public class JavaStringReplaceExample{

    public static void main(String args[])
{

String str="abcdefghabcd";

 System.out.println(str.replaceFirst("a", "0"));
}
 }
```

you can refer to [here](http://www.javadeveloper.co.in/java-example/java-string-replace-example.html) for details

Comment: I would recommend against providing links to RoseIndia in the future, their posts about Java are known to often contain deprecated code and/or bad practices.